# Error when I include C in C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to include a C code, "config.h", in a C++ code using:

```
extern "C"
{
#include "config.h"
}
```

If I compile "config.h" separately with gcc I get no errors, but when I compile the C++ code with g++ I get the following error:

***invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘char*’***.

The error points to the following line from "config.h":

```
newsect->name = malloc(strlen(config));
```

where config is of type char*.

Can anyone please tell me how to make this work? Thank you in advance!

Comment: That line is valid in C because `void *` (which is returned by `malloc`) can be implicitly converted to another type. C++ does not have the same behavior. You'll have to add a cast like `(char*)` to make it legal C++.

Comment: why is there code in your header?

Comment: Thank you for the fast answers. (char *) solved almost all errors. I have one more error though: "cannot convert ‘char*’ to ‘section*’ in initialization", from line : psection newsect = (char *) malloc(sizeof(struct section));, where I define: typedef struct section * psection;

Comment: @RazvanBucoveanu - sounds like you need to use `(psection)` as a cast for that one.

Comment: @sp2danny makes a good point. Statements can appear only inside function bodies which should not be in headers (unless *maybe* there's some kind of inlining going on).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`name` is probably a `char *`, so just use:

```
newsect->name = (char *)malloc(strlen(config));
```

Hope this helps!